# Distance of nearby points in the Ring of Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

My book says that the distance of two nearby points in $\mathbb{Z}(i)$ is maximum $\sqrt{2}$. But $|(3+2i)-(3+3i)|=|i|=1$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Diagonal entries.

Comment: hey, thx. could you please explain that a bit?

Comment: What do you mean by nearby points?

Comment: neighboring points maybe? sorry for my english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(3+3i)−(2+2i)|=|1+i|=\sqrt 2$.

$|1+i| = \sqrt{(1+i)(1-i)} = \sqrt{1-i^2} = \sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt 2$.

In general, $|z| = \sqrt{z\cdot\overline z}$, where $\overline z$ is the conjugate of $z$.

Comment: why did the books say neighboring points then... makes no sense to me. what you write is obviously correct. thank you.